# Как добавить RecyclerView во ViewPager 2?

Tags: android, android-studio, recyclerview, android-viewpager

У меня есть список дат и вьюпейджер со страницами на каждую из этих дат. Мне нужно на каждом экране реализовать по ресайклервью со списком айтемов кторые относятся к этой дате. Проблема в том что я не могу реализовать ресайклервью внутри вьюпейджера.
Вот мой код:

Вот адаптер:

```
    class ViewPagerAdapter(private val dates: List<String>, private val exerciseList: List<Exercise>) :
        RecyclerView.Adapter<ViewPagerAdapter.Pager2ViewHolder>() {
    
    
    
        inner class Pager2ViewHolder(itemView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView) {
            val dateTitle: TextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.date_tv)
            val recyclerView: RecyclerView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.main_recycler_view)
    
            init {
    
                //todo click to comeback on current date
                dateTitle.setOnClickListener {
                    val position: Int = adapterPosition
                    Toast.makeText(
                        itemView.context,
                        "You cliked on iten ${position + 1}",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT
                    ).show()
                }
            }
        }
    
        override fun onCreateViewHolder(
            parent: ViewGroup,
            viewType: Int
        ): ViewPagerAdapter.Pager2ViewHolder {
            return Pager2ViewHolder(
                LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.item_page, parent, false)
            )
        }
    
        override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ViewPagerAdapter.Pager2ViewHolder, position: Int) {
            holder.dateTitle.text = dates[position]
            holder.recyclerView.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(requireContext(),LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false)
            val adapter = ExerciseMainRecyclerAdapter(exerciseList)
            holder.recyclerView.adapter = adapter
        }
    
        override fun getItemCount(): Int {
            return dates.size
        }

}
```

в нем я не могу передать LinearLayoutManager контекст, ну потому что это адаптер. А где собственно ресайклер реализовывать я не понял. Вроде же в адаптере, потому что здесь есть вьюхолдер куда можно пихать элементы.

Если есть другие предложения как построить мою задумку то я готов все передеать. Главное чтобы свайпы лево вправо навигация по дням, а вниз вверх листать это список из айтемов которые соответствуют этому дню(у них один макет на все дни). Я уже пару дней не могу это решить.

Answer (score 0):

```kotlin
val fragments = listOf(
   Fragment1(),
   Fragment2(),
   Fragment3()
)

val fragmentAdapter = MainFragmentStateAdapter(
   fragments = fragments,
   fragmentManager = childFragmentManager,
   lifecycle = lifecycle
)

binding.viewPagerViewId.adapter = fragmentAdapter
```

```kotlin
class MainFragmentStateAdapter(
    fragments: List<Fragment>,
    fragmentManager: FragmentManager,
    lifecycle: Lifecycle
) : FragmentStateAdapter(fragmentManager, lifecycle) {
    private val _fragments: List<Fragment> = fragments

    override fun getItemCount(): Int =
        _fragments.size

    override fun createFragment(position: Int): Fragment =
        _fragments[position]
}
```

А уже в самих `Fragment1`, `Fragment2`, `Fragment3` реализуете `RecyclerView` со своими адаптерами.

Comment: А если у меня этих фрагментов будет около 500 штук? Это коректно работать будет?

Comment: @PublicOverdose Относительно. Можно решить задачу хранением во ```ViewModel``` отметки даты. Во фрагментах прослушивать эту переменную и на основе этого загружать нужные данные. ```ViewPager2``` зациклить с 3-мя фрагментами и "слушать" свайп. При свайпе менять переменную во ```ViewModel```. Это все теория, на практике не проверял.